# Render two model forms as one

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have two models defined as:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    OS_CHOICE=(('Win 2003','windows 2003'),
        ('Win 2008','Windows 2008'),
        ('Win XP','Windows XP'),
        ('Win VISTA','Win VISTA'),
        ('Win 2007','Windows 2007'),
        )
    windows=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=OS_CHOICE,default='Win 2003')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " %s, event_id :%s" \
            % (self.windows, self.event_id)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'event'
        verbose_name_plural='events'


class Eventgroups(models.Model):
    event=models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    group_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s,  %s" \
            % (self.group_name, self.event)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'eventgroup'
        verbose_name_plural='eventgroups'
```

I would like to render two model forms from these two models.
I want a way to render this forms as if it was one form.
Anyone with an insight on how to achieve this please?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need them to look like one form you could do something like this:

In your views.py you'd want to instantiate the form variables as follows:

```
event_form = EventForm(prefix='event')
event_groups_form = EventForm(prefix='event_groups')
```

Then you could render the forms as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% for field in event_form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in event_groups_form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Then in your views you could read the data into the forms as follows:

```
event_form = EventForm(request.POST, prefix='event')
event_groups_form = EventForm(request.POST, prefix='event_groups')
```

Note: The prefix is important if you might have conflicting fields within the forms which you don't currently, but could in the future.